# Update query is not working: Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm used to write the update query but for now it's not working for me in laravel.
I have write the update query like this.

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(['id'=>$requst_id])->update(array('status'=>$status)
```

When i run dd().it's getting 0 to me

But with same condition i used

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(['id'=>$requst_id])->first();
```

I got the data.
Can anyone suggest me where i'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is missing closing `)` a typo?

Comment: `dd(DB::table('table_name')->where('id'=>$requst_id)->get());` please check what return this code?   and `DB::table('table_name')->where('id'=>$requst_id)->update(array('status'=>$status));`

Comment: @Amir its was copy error. if there is a syntax error it won't return ZERO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $requst_id)->update(array('status'=>$status));
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because `UPDATE` return count and `SELECT` returns data/array.

**This is `SELECT`**

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(['id'=>$requst_id])->first();
```

**This is `UPDATE`**

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(['id'=>$requst_id])->update(array('status'=>$status));
```

---

Do like this

```
$affectedRows = DB::table('table_name')->where(['id'=>$requst_id])->update(array('status'=>$status));
echo "Affected rows are/is: " . $affectedRows;
```

If Prints

1. 0 - No Changes
2. 1 - One row was changed
3. 1> - N number of rows updated.

---

Might helps [Echoing: `dd()` vs `var_dump()` vs `print_r()`](http://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/)

Answer (score 0):

Update like this

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $requst_id)->update(array('status'=>$status));
```

Comment: none of the above helped. The database is MySQL 5.6, and the field in question is an enum. I have tried all the above approached to no avail. But writing a raw query on the database itself works (its how they've been doing it) it just does not work in code.